# setTimeout() not executing desired function?

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout

I'm working on a project for school, and I've used a setTimeout() function to execute my flawlessWin function, but it's not executing it. I think I used to right syntax, but I'm new to Javascript, so I may just not see something obvious. Any help or suggestions is appreciated!

I've looked up the syntax to make sure everything is right, and it looks right. I really don't know why it isn't working.

Link to the code - https://codepen.io/Jacob-Bruce/pen/mQgbXa

```
    function executeTimeout() {
  setTimeout(flawlessWin, 100);
};  
function flawlessWin() {
   ctx.font = "30px Arial";
   ctx.fillText("Flawless Victory!", canvas.width/3, canvas.height/3)
};
// collision
function collisionDetection() {
  for(var c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) {
    for(var r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) {
      var b = bricks[c][r];
      if(b.status == 1) {
        if(x > b.x && x < b.x+brickWidth && y > b.y && y < 
           b.y+brickHeight) {
          dy = -dy;
          b.status = 0;
          score++;
          // win condition - find out why the AND log. operator isn't 
              working

          if(score == brickRowCount*brickColumnCount) {
              executetimeout();

          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I expect the flawlessWin function to be executed once the timeout is executed.

Comment: You might just have a typo: you call `executetimeout()` but your function name is `executeTimeout()`. Also `working` is not part of your comment. If that's your code verbatim then it will cause syntax errors.

Comment: sorry to confused, the 'working' is part of it, it just got pushed down a line I guess. But I fixed the typo, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo. Your function is `executeTimeout()`, but when you call it inside of

```
if (score == brickRowCount*brickColumnCount) {
  executetimeout();
}
```

the first "t" in timeout isn't capitalized. JavaScript is case sensitive.

Comment: It's not even freezing the canvas anymore now, I don't know why.

Comment: It was freezing before because your code was throwing an exception due to the undefined function call. Check that your win condition is being hit, and if/when it is, then you may need to `return` or somehow break out of the collision detection, and stop the animation.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who upvoted! Jacob, I don't know how to fix that, but I guess Cory cleared that up for you!

Answer (score 3):

```
function executeTimeout() {
  //setTimeout(flawlessWin, 100);
    setTimeout(function () {
         flawlessWin();  
         }, 100);
};
```

> I think you need to use this syntax to use set timeout function,i hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is extremely case sensitive, so when you say

```
executetimeout();
```

It should be

```
executeTimeout();
```